# How to solve a Fredholm integral equation of the second kind with a logarithmic kernel function between 0 and 1?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, integral-equations

Consider the following Fredholm integral equation of the second kind
$$
 \phi(s) = \frac{s(1-s^2)}{(1+s^2)^4} + \lambda \int_0^1 \phi(t) \ln \left| \frac{s+t}{s-t} \right| \, \mathrm{d} t \, , \quad\quad (0<s<1) \, ,
$$
wherein $\lambda$ is a  known quantity and $\phi(s)$ is the unknown function.
I have tried to use the method of successive substitution but it turns out to be inconvenient for a logarithmic kernel function.

I was wondering whether other analytical approaches can be employed for this case.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

R